# Free Screenrecording Software for Windows with Area Selection and User-Input Visualization

Tags: gratis, windows-10, screen-recording

I'm searching for a free (preferably open source) video recording software with the following specs:

1. Works 100% offline
2. Runs on Windows 10
3. Allows me to capture an area of the screen instead of the full screen
4. Has some means to visualize *off-screen* user input (shows when a mouse click occurs or a keyboard shortcut is pressed)
5. Allows me to save the recording to mp4 or gif format

So far I tried screenrec but that fails on #4. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Broadcast Studio ([OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/)) covers all the points.

- It is a free, stand-alone download that works on Windows 10.
- It runs on Windows 10 (current version does not work on W7)
- Confirmed  from the site features list that one can select active window to capture
- Plug-ins exist for OBS Studio to enable display of keystrokes and mouse actions. One such plug-in is called [Input Overlay](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/input-overlay.552/) and may not be exactly what you require, but there are more than a couple in the OBS Studio environment. YouTube video at the linked site shows this specific feature.
- Confirmed file format output (MP4) from forum post at linked site "change the file extension for the path to MP4 under Settings > Broadcast Settings."